# Handlebars Template: Print values from multiple arrays into a table

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to print multiple arrays into a table. The data is contained in two arrays and it is like a name value pair. I am not sure of the handlebar syntax so any help is appreciated

Arrays from Javascript are as follows:
    keys = {"name", "age", "address"};
    values = {"AD", "2", "123st"};

The handlebars (version 1.0 rc2) template looks like below but does not seem to print anything. Any hints?

```
<table>
    {{#each keys}}
        <tr>
            <td> {{keys.@index}}</td>
            <td> {{values.@index}} </td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Comment: I think, you have to merge the arrays before rendering :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that the arrays in your question are not valid JavaScript syntax and should be wrapped in square-brackets instead of braces (ex., `["name", "age", "address"]`).

I think your data structure could be improved upon and I would recommend merging those two arrays of strings into a single object:

```
{
    name: 'AD',
    age: '2',
    address: '123st'
}
```

We could create a new template that would iterate over each property in our object and we could access the key with [Handlbars' built-in `{{@key}}`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration):

```
<script id="Template1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
        {{#each this}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{@key}}</td>
                <td>{{this}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

If, for some reason, you must stick with the two arrays, we can use [Handlebars' lookup helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) to access the the require property on the `values` array:

```
<script id="Template2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
        {{#each keys}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this}}</td>
                <td>{{lookup ../values @index}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

Comment: what if I want the keys in <thead> and values in <tbody>?

Comment: @MuhFred: Then you would loop over `keys` twice.

Comment: I know that. i'm just having some trouble writing the template/html code. could you please help me? thanks.

Comment: @MuhFred: Please create a new question, stating your problem and including your relevant code and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: It will be a duplicate question. I can start a bounty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809752/how-to-render-dynamic-table-without-knowing-the-data-using-html-and-js