# How to render dynamic table without knowing the data? using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

By dynamic I mean that I don't know what is the data returned from the ajax response. I managed to return `{name:"" value:""}` pair for some leverage.

sample data:

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "_id",
      "value": "5a32391133425e1f5436161b"
    },
    {
      "name": "Issue",
      "value": "Splash Screen Animations"
    },
    {
      "name": "Status",
      "value": "Done"
    },
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "value": "The animation must be the same as ios"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "_id",
      "value": "5a32391133425e1f5436161c"
    },
    {
      "name": "Issue",
      "value": "Live Streaming Title and Image"
    },
    {
      "name": "Status",
      "value": "Done"
    },
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "value": "asdasd"
    }
  ],
]
```

**So How to render these data in a table or handlebars template?**. knowing that the name should be in `<thead>` and the value should be in `<tbody>`

I also managed to separate the response data into separate arrays (headers, and data) so I can render the table as following.

```js
<script type="text/html" id="ViewDataTemplate">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {{#each headers}}
                <th>{{this}}</th>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                {{#each this}}
                    <td>{{this}}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

**Please note**: that the answer that I'm looking for is not specific to handlebars, html/js should be enough.

Comment: What is the problem? Generally, the response `data` should have a length so that length will be your table's rows number via any mean of looping supported by the template or technology that you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown us what your separated data looks like (`headers` and `data`), but it is quite possible that you could get the result you want simply by adding the missing `.value` reference within your body cell output:

```
{{#each this}}
    <td>{{this.value}}</td>
{{/each}}
```

That approach can work, but it makes some assumptions about the structure of your data. Most importantly, it assumes that each row object has the *exact* same properties and that the property objects are *always* in the same order ("_id", "Issue", "Status", "Comment").

If you are that confident in the consistency of your data, then I wouldn't even bother with the separation of the data into `headers` and `data`. I would simply get the column headings from the first row object, render those, and then `#each` over the entire data array to render the body. The template would be:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each (lookup this 0)}}
                <th>{{this.name}}</th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each this}}
            <tr>
                {{#each this}}
                    <td>{{this.value}}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The only interesting part of this template is the use of the [lookup](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) helper. This is used to get us just the first array in our data object - the first "row" - which we use to populate our column headings.

Again, this will work *only* if your data is structured so that each row has the same columns object and those objects are in the same order. If your data is less predictable, then a more involved solution is required. I can provide that if necessary.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/n6c03acs/) for your reference.