# Handlebars HBS Express - How to iterate an object without specify the properties

Tags: handlebars.js, each, hbs

I am trying to iterate using the properties of an object to dynamically print a table having an array with the properties and an object with the values ​​of each property.

I don't know how to do the 2 iterations using hbs express from handlebars

```
people: [{
    name: "ken",
    lastname: "grace",
    age: 10
},
{
    name: "ron",
    lastname: "bond",
    age: 20
}];

properties = ["name","lastname", "age"];
```

HTML CODE:

```
<table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {{#each properties as |property index|}}
                                    <th>
                                        <span>{{property}}</span>
                                    </th>
                                {{/each}}
                            </tr>
                            
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {{#each people}}
                                <tr>
                                    {{#each properties}}
                                        <th>
                                            {{!-- trying something like: --}}
                                            {{!-- {{people.property}} --}}
                                        </th>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </tr>
                            {{/each}}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: This post might be of some help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814775/3397771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @76484 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816070/handlebars-hbs-express-how-to-iterate-an-object-without-specify-the-properties#comment125197754_70816070), you want to use the built-in [`lookup` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup):

> The `lookup` helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables. It can be used to look up properties of object based on data from the input.

In your specific example, you'd probably want to store your `people` and `properties` iterations in a [block parameter](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#block-parameters) (e.g., named `|person|` and `|property|`), as well as using `../` on your inner loop since the [context](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context) has changed.

Putting that all together for you example, the HBS markup might look like:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {{#each properties as |property index|}}
                <th><span>{{property}}</span></th>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each people as |person|}}
            <tr>
                {{#each ../properties as |property|}}
                    <th>{{lookup person property}}</th>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [this playground link](https://handlebarsjs.com/playground.html#format=1&currentExample=%7B%22template%22%3A%22%3Ctable%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3Cthead%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20properties%20as%20%7Cproperty%20index%7C%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%3Cspan%3E%7B%7Bproperty%7D%7D%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fthead%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20people%20as%20%7Cperson%7C%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%23each%20..%2Fproperties%20as%20%7Cproperty%7C%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%7B%7Blookup%20person%20(property)%7D%7D%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%7B%2Feach%7D%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%5Cn%3C%2Ftable%3E%22%2C%22partials%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22input%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20people%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%5C%22ken%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20lastname%3A%20%5C%22grace%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2010%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%5C%22ron%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20lastname%3A%20%5C%22bond%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20age%3A%2020%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5D%2C%5Cn%20%20properties%3A%20%5B%5C%22name%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22lastname%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22age%5C%22%5D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%2C%22output%22%3A%22%3Ctable%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3Cthead%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%3Cspan%3Ename%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%3Cspan%3Elastname%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%3Cspan%3Eage%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fthead%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3Ctbody%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Eken%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Egrace%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E10%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Eron%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Ebond%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E20%3C%2Fth%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%5Cn%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftbody%3E%5Cn%3C%2Ftable%3E%22%2C%22preparationScript%22%3A%22%5Cn%22%2C%22handlebarsVersion%22%3A%224.7.7%22%7D) for the resulting HTML as well.